# Error using Postgres with Sails.js on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, sails.js, waterline, sails-postgresql

Thanks in advance for any help.

Sails: ~0.10.0

DB: Postgres using sails-postgresql adapter

I've successfully deployed my Sails app to Heroku and am able to connect to it in the browser.  However, I try to create any data using blueprints or by using my api, I get the following error

```
2015-08-08T12:59:48.540049+00:00 app[web.1]: Lowering sails...
2015-08-08T12:59:48.540921+00:00 app[web.1]: Shutting down socket server...
2015-08-08T12:59:48.581335+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-49-generic
2015-08-08T12:59:48.587661+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2015-08-08T12:59:48.587787+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2015-08-08T12:59:48.540339+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent kill signal to child process (26)...
2015-08-08T12:59:48.544026+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/sails-postgresql/lib/adapter.js:393
2015-08-08T12:59:48.544029+00:00 app[web.1]:         Object.keys(collection.schema).forEach(function(schemaKey) {
2015-08-08T12:59:48.544032+00:00 app[web.1]:                ^
2015-08-08T12:59:48.544033+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
2015-08-08T12:59:48.544035+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.keys (native)
2015-08-08T12:59:48.544036+00:00 app[web.1]:     at __CREATE__ (/app/node_modules/sails-postgresql/lib/adapter.js:393:16)
2015-08-08T12:59:48.544038+00:00 app[web.1]:     at after (/app/node_modules/sails-postgresql/lib/adapter.js:1206:7)
2015-08-08T12:59:48.544039+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/sails-postgresql/lib/adapter.js:1100:7
2015-08-08T12:59:48.544041+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/sails-postgresql/node_modules/pg/lib/pool.js:77:9
2015-08-08T12:59:48.544042+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/sails-postgresql/node_modules/pg/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:281:11
2015-08-08T12:59:48.544044+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/sails-postgresql/node_modules/pg/lib/pool.js:51:18
2015-08-08T12:59:48.544046+00:00 app[web.1]:     at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/sails-postgresql/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:149:7)
2015-08-08T12:59:48.544047+00:00 app[web.1]:     at g (events.js:199:16)
2015-08-08T12:59:48.544048+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emit (events.js:129:20)
2015-08-08T12:59:48.544050+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/sails-postgresql/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:109:12)
2015-08-08T12:59:48.544051+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:107:17)
2015-08-08T12:59:48.544052+00:00 app[web.1]:     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
2015-08-08T12:59:48.544054+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
2015-08-08T12:59:48.544055+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TCP.onread (net.js:538:20)
```

I'm unable to create any data in the database.  When I connect to my Heroku Postgres DB remotely, I also notice that there aren't any tables created.  What is missing in my configuration?

Comment: Why use such old version? 0.11 was released 6 month ago.

Comment: @vitaly-t That did it.  It seems heroku and sails-postgresql didn't like the old version of sails. I upgraded and everything worked smoothly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Upgraded to sails v11 and everything worked.  Thanks @vitaly-t

Comment: I'm on sails 0.11.2 and I have this same error. Any idea ?

Comment: @PhilippeDavid do you have blueprints enabled? Also, did you verify that you're connected to the correct DB and that it's up and running?

Comment: Yes and Yes. I fixed my problem by running the migration:alter with dev env and forcing schema:true.